# Output of python code is one character per line

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm new to Python and having some trouble with an API scraping I'm attempting. What I want to do is pull a list of book titles using this code:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.dp.la/v2/items?q=magic+AND+wizard&api_key=09a0efa145eaa3c80f6acf7c3b14b588')

data = json.loads(r.text)

for doc in data["docs"]:
    for title in doc["sourceResource"]["title"]:
        print (title)
```

Which works to pull the titles, but most (not all) titles are outputting as one character per line. I've tried adding .splitlines() but this doesn't fix the problem. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You iterating over the title, printing it character by character. Just do `print(doc["sourceResource"]["title"])`.

Comment: Thank you @Loocid! That's so much easier than I thought it would be. Appreciate the help for a newbie.

Comment: also, if you know the response content-type will always be `application/json`, then you can replace `json.loads(r.text)` with `r.json()`. This would also get rid of `import json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two types of title in the response, some are plain strings `"Germain the wizard"` and some others are arrays of string `['Joe Strong, the boy wizard : or, The mysteries of magic exposed /']`. It seems like in this particular case, all lists have length one, but I guess that will not always be the case. To illustrate what you might need to do I added a `join` here instead of just taking `title[0]`.

```py
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.dp.la/v2/items?q=magic+AND+wizard&api_key=09a0efa145eaa3c80f6acf7c3b14b588')

data = json.loads(r.text)

for doc in data["docs"]:
  title = doc["sourceResource"]["title"]
  if isinstance(title, list):
    print(" ".join(title))
  else:
    print(title)
```

In my opinion that should never happen, an API should return predictable types, otherwise it looks messy on the users' side.